# What's the difference between $∀x\,∃y\,L(x, y)$ and $∃y\,∀x\,L(x, y)$?

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

1. *Everybody loves somebody.* $∀x\,∃y\,L(x, y)$
2. *There is somebody whom everybody loves.* $∃y\,∀x\,L(x, y)$

What's the difference between these two sentences? If they are same, can I switch $\exists y$ and $\forall x$?

Comment: Consider a world where people only love themselves.

Comment: Suppose there are three people in the world: Ann, Bob, and Chuck. Suppose that Ann loves Bob, Bob loves Ann, Chuck loves Ann, but nobody loves Chuck. Is statement 1 true? Is statement 2 true?

Comment: It's even possible with only two people: $A$ and $B$, each loving the other only.

Comment: There's a difference between one for all and all for one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unus_pro_omnibus,_omnes_pro_uno

Comment: @AsafKaragila What a sad world.  Couldn't you assume a better world?

Comment: Suppose the variables range over **real numbers** instead of people, and $L(x,y)$ means "$x\lt y.$ Is the first sentence true or false? Is the second one true or false?

Comment: @SimpleArt How about a world where everybody loves everybody else but not himself/herself?

Comment: @AndreasBlass Lmao, I love everyone here *and* myself.  That's the world I wanna live in.

Comment: @Ned Stack : for every person, there is a jacket that has the suitable size for that person. However, it is not true that there is a jacket that suits every person.

Answer (score 36):

In 1, everybody loves someone, be it $y$ or $z$. In 2, everybody loves $y$.

[image]

2 is stronger than 1: 2 implies 1 but not conversely.

Comment: Very clear example! :D

Comment: In either case, I predict a drama between the four people involved. Why can it never be as simple as $x \leftrightarrows y$ and $z \leftrightarrows t$?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: $\forall x,\exists y:L(x,y)\land L(y,x)\land\forall z\ne x,y:\lnot L(x,z)\land\lnot L(y,z)$ maybe.

Answer (score 13):

I'm late to the party but:  replace "loves somebody" with "has someone as a mother".

Everbody has a mother.

vs.

There is somebody who is everybody's mother.

?????

Answer (score 10):

That's a great example of why quantifiers don't commute! For the sake of simplicity, assume everybody in the world is married, and everybody loves his spouse.  Then the first formula is satisfied.  However, there is no reason to think that the second formula is satisfied; in fact, it could be that people only love their spouses, so that there is nobody in the world who is loved by *everybody*.

Comment: At first, I wanted to joke that your counterexample doesn't hold in a world with extreme polygamy, but then I realized that that would require people to be able to marry themselves.

Answer (score 7):

There are already some fantastic answers here. But I wanted to add a discussion about *why* quantifiers don't commute, and what we even mean by quantifiers.

So what doe we mean by: $\forall a \ \exists \, b \ P(a, b)$? Well, it means that if I choose to fix any $a$, then given this information, I can find a $b$ which has $P(a,b)$ being true. That is, $b$ is dependent on $a$. To make this clear, we sometimes write:

$$ \forall a \ \exists \, b(a) \ \ P(a, b) \qquad \text{or alternatively} \qquad \forall a \ \exists \, b_a \ \ \ \  P(a, b) $$

Conversely, $\exists b \ \forall a \ P(a, b)$ means, that with no knowledge of $a$, I can find a $b$ which satisfies $P(a, b)$ - or in other words, I can find a $b$ working for all $a$.

**In essence:**
In the first case, you can think of $b$ as a function of $a$ - it could be a different $b$ for each $a$. In the second case, we must have that $b$ can be constant, that is, independent of the choice of $a$.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone likes some sweet.

There is one sweet liked by everyone.

First one allows the interpretation which sweet is liked by whom is individual choice.

Second sentence says there is a universally liked sweet.

Answer (score 2):

If $L$ satisfies 2., then it necessarily satisfies 1. Therefore you can switch $\exists y$ and $\forall x$ to go from 2. to 1., but not the other way around. Counterexample: let $L$ be a relation over set $S=\{a,b,c\}$, and suppose $L(a,b)$, $L(b,c)$, $L(c,a)$. You can easily verify that 1. holds here, but 2. does not.